# Java - Traverse list till parent

Tags: java

I've a result set like:

```
Id  Name    Parent
1   Adam    null
2   George  1
3   Ashley  null
4   Ric     2
5   Adele   4
```

In input I might get any Ids, say: 2,3 & 5.

Now I have translate them into value object from provided Ids to their top parent.

**MyVO class:**

```
class MyVO {
  private String name;
  private Set<MyVO> child;
}
```

So for Ids 2,3 & 5, structure should look like:

```
Adam
  - George
    - Ric
      - Adele
Ashley
```

One way to do it do it in linear fashion and continue while parent is not null.

But I'm new to `Java 8` and wondering if this logic can be improved.

Comment: With "Java 8" you're refering to streams, aren't you?

Comment: @Thomas, yes. But I'm also not sure if there is something better available.

Comment: Could elaborate a little, i.e. what exactly you want to get? Also, "continue while parent is not null" wouldn't match your VO code since it doesn't have a `parent` but I assume you actually have that reference to the parent as well. I further assume your input states the nodes that have to be in the result along with all of their parents. Could elaborate how your are doing it without streams? Do you have a mapping to quickly get the "starting" nodes? Do you require any ordering?